# virtual terminal in proteus is not showing values?

Tags: arduino

```
int val=0;
void setup()
{
Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop() {

val = analogRead(A1);
Serial.println("the ldr intensity");
Serial.println(val);
delay(1000);
}
```

[image: this is the error i am getting after putting the hex file and running]

Comment: I am not too sure how this works on a simulator but on real HW I think you will need a GND between two UART devices. This is my experience.

Comment: where should i add the ground plz tell... and ia changed the code...just declared "int ldr =A1"

Comment: still not working

Comment: It appears you are not synchronizing your RX and TX signals and or your "enable" signal.

Comment: How does the program know it is supposed to send the readings to the virtual terminal?